# c# Как сделать планировщик задач?

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь сделать планировщик задач, нужно запускать .exe файл каждый час, использую [TaskScheduler](https://github.com/dahall/TaskScheduler/)

код:

```
   // Create a new task definition for the local machine and assign properties
        TaskDefinition td = TaskService.Instance.NewTask();
        td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Test Task";

        // Add a trigger that, starting tomorrow, will fire every other week on Monday
        // and Saturday and repeat every 10 minutes for the following 11 hours
        WeeklyTrigger wt = new WeeklyTrigger();
       
        wt.DaysOfWeek = DaysOfTheWeek.Monday | DaysOfTheWeek.Saturday | DaysOfTheWeek.Sunday | DaysOfTheWeek.Thursday | DaysOfTheWeek.Tuesday | DaysOfTheWeek.Wednesday | DaysOfTheWeek.Friday;
      
        wt.Repetition.Duration = TimeSpan.FromHours(11);
        wt.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
        td.Triggers.Add(wt);

        // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
        td.Actions.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        // Register the task in the root folder of the local machine
        TaskService.Instance.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("Test Task", td);
```

Задача появляеться в планировщике задач, время последнего выполнения пишет "30.11.1999", после того как наступает время выполнения задачи - в логе планировщика пишет (0xE0434352), задача не выполняеться.

Comment: Пишете ради самообучения, надеюсь? Потому что планировщик есть системный, то есть велосипед уже существует.

Comment: @aepot, мне нужно раз в час проверять работает ли приложение, хочу с помощью планировщика запускать его каждый час, при запуске приложения я проверяю не было ли оно запущено раньше, если приложение не запущено - запускаю его, если запущено - просто завершаю процесс. Как это лучше всего реализовать? спасибо!

Comment: [вот так](https://www.comss.ru/page.php?id=4840) - 0 строк кода.

Comment: @aepot, то есть вы предлагаете настраивать планировщик вручную?

Comment: Вам в любом случае настраивать планировщик, будь то ваш собственный велик или системный планировщик. С системным на самом деле проще, и может он гораздо больше всяких штук вытворять.

Comment: А вообще гуглить такие штуки, если вам нужен перезапускающий омеханизм, можно по ключевому слову "watchdog" = "сторожевая собака", это процесс по сути следящий за другими процессами. В вашем случае этим процессом может быть планировщик Windows.